# About the limit of the absolute value of a function

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value

I'm trying to prove $\lim _{x\to x_0}f\left(x\right)=L$ then $\lim _{x\to x_0}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|=\left|L\right|$ (for $L\geq  0$ of course).

I proved it for $L = 0$ but struggled to prove it for $L > 0$.
Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but isn't this trivially obvious?  If the initial statement is true, doesn't adding the absolute value operator *loosen* the requirement?  (In other words, the second statement is true even if L is the *negative* of the left side of the first equation.)

Comment: I think that you do not need that $L\ge 0$ as you state in the parenthesis, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy proof of the general statement is to use the reverse triangle inequality:
$$\Big||f(x)|-|L|\Big|\leq |f(x)-L|$$ 
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Since $f(x)\rightarrow L$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$0<|x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$
The triangle inequality gives then that
$$0<|x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow \Big||f(x)|-|L|\Big|<\varepsilon$$
which means that $|f(x)|\rightarrow |L|$. Alternatively, you could summon the squeeze theorem.

Comment: thanks!
Can I say the opposite? 
means if $limx→x0|f(x)|=|L|$ so the limit of f(x) is either L or -L?

Comment: @DolevBinness: No,for instance $f(x)=-1$ if $x \in \mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ is standard counterexample.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can imagine a function $f(x)$ which hops faster and faster between the values $L$ and $-L$ as $x\rightarrow x_0$. Then $|f(x)|$ is equal to $|L|$ while $f$ does not have a limit.